# google speed test (Сократите глубину вложенности критических запросов)

Tags: nuxt.js, pagespeed-insights

Всем привет.
Есть одна(пока что) страница:
http://webmaster.ayrveda.ru/perfect_goods/

Пытаюсь понять что от меня требует гугл спид тест:

"1. Сократите глубину вложенности критических запросов"
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmaster.ayrveda.ru%2Fperfect_goods%2F&tab=mobile

Вопрос:
Что я должен исправить в данном случае?
(О чем вообще речь идет?)
О какого рода цепочках и вызовах?

P.S. Сам верстальщик, проект выполнен на Nuxt.js

Comment: Насколько я помню, это решается добавлением вложенного ресурса в link rel="preload"

Comment: Проблема еще в том что я не совсем понимаю как вообще стили подключаются в Nuxt.js )
Все что я могу наблюдать в файле nuxt.config.js это:
http://joxi.ru/VrwyX78cOP06W2 и там просто не куда добавлять атрибут который вы упоминаете. )